# Require_once(Net/URL2.php): failed to open stream: no such file or directory

Tags: php, composer-php, pear

I installed the `pear/http_request2` version `2.2.1` using Composer in my project but when I am trying to make my first request I am getting this Warning and Fatal error:

> Warning: require_once(Net/URL2.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jet/vendor/pear/http_request2/HTTP/Request2.php
>   on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Net/URL2.php'
>   (include_path='/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jet/vendor/pear/pear_exception:.:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php')
>   in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/jet/vendor/pear/http_request2/HTTP/Request2.php
>   on line 24

I appreciate any help on how to fix it, thanks in advance.

David.

Comment: Are the files where they should be? If not, you should put them there.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
composer require pear/http_request2:2.2.1
```

By default `pear/net_url2` should be installed which has the required `URL2.php` file (`./vendor/pear/net_url2/Net/URL2.php`).

Then make sure you're including `vendor/autoload.php` file in your scripts to load automatically the include paths (see: `vendor/composer/include_paths.php` file).

Here is a simple PHP command to test this out:

```
php -r 'require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; require_once "Net/URL2.php";'
```

<sup>Note: The above command should run without any errors.</sup>

Related: [Errors in the autoloaded HTTP/Request2 code, how to troubleshoot composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45094277/55075)

Answer (score 0):

You need `HTTP_Request2` from git `master`, because [it has not been released/tagged yet](https://github.com/pear/HTTP_Request2/commit/0b422776d1f01725a30f0f586ee73e3afb678bb8) at the time of writing.