# Errors in the autoloaded HTTP/Request2 code, how to troubleshoot composer?

Tags: composer-php

I have two different systems with a git repository cloned on them.
the project uses composer to install various dependencies.
One of these is `pear/HTTP_Request2` which requires `Net/URL2`.
Both systems are Windows with a xampp development enviroment. So both run an Apache2 with a PHP 7.1.* installation.

On one of them everything works perfectly after installing via `composer install`. But the other one always Errors in the autoloaded HTTP/Request2 code:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  require_once(Net/URL2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\vendor\pear\http_request2\HTTP\Request2.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'Net/URL2.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\vendor/pear/pear_exception;C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\vendor/pear/http_request2;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\XXX\vendor\pear\http_request2\HTTP\Request2.php</b> on line <b>25</b><br />
```

Looking at the code in the Package we find:

```
if (!class_exists('Net_URL2', true)) {
    require_once 'Net/URL2.php';
}
```

The dependency of NetURL2 was successfully installed, judging by composers output.

None the less I tried to fix it by also requiring the dependency from HTTP/Request2 `"pear/net_url2"       : "^2.2.0",` in the Project after i heard from a bug (long closed but still) about problems with that ([Issue@composer git](http://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2987)), which didn't result in a change.

Judging by the inspected code I also assume [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31484814/require-oncenet-url2-php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory) is outdated.

Now I'm stuck not knowing what to do next... Help?

Edit:
My composer.json essentially looks like this if anyone was wondering:

```
{
"require":
  {
    "php":">=7.1.4",
    "pear/http_request2": "v2.3.0",
    "ext-json":"1.5.0",
    "ext-PDO":"7.*",
    "ext-pdo_mysql":"7.*",
    "ext-mbstring":"7.*",
    "ext-gd":"7.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "files": [
      "helper.php",
      "settings.php"
    ],
    "classmap": ["./"],
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["vendor/"]

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot *Composer* in general, you can add `-vvv` flags for verbose information.

Secondly, when you've [XDebug](https://xdebug.org/) extension for PHP installed, you will see a *Call Stack* each time when a *Fatal error* happens.

<sup>Note: Run `phpenmod -s cli xdebug` to enable XDebug in CLI mode.</sup>

---

The fatal error happens in [`pear/http_request2` package](http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) (as per [`vendor/pear/http_request2/HTTP/Request2.php`](https://github.com/pear/HTTP_Request2/blob/trunk/HTTP/Request2.php)) when it tries to include `Net/URL2.php` file (part of `pear/net_url2`, full path: `vendor/pear/net_url2/Net/URL2.php`).

This path should normally be added by Composer into `include_paths.php` like:

```
vendor/composer/include_paths.php:    $vendorDir . '/pear/net_url2',
```

which failed to do so. To generate autoload files again, run this command:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

and check whether the autoload files under `vendor/composer` has been generated as expected.

To test that out, I've run this PHP command and it worked:

```
php -r 'require_once "vendor/autoload.php"; require_once "vendor/pear/http_request2/HTTP/Request2.php";'
```

<sup>Note: To see the failing scenario, remove include of `autoload.php`.</sup>